# Java logging API MemoryHandler dumping log instantly

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I want to log my application's messages after certain threshold. Say after 10 messages. I read about memory handler and used it. However I found that it logs the messages instantly instead of buffering them as said in documentation. Here's code

```
Handler h = new FileHandler('/var/tmp/process.log',Level.INFO);
Handler h2 = new MemoryHandler(h, 10, Level.ALL);
logger.addHandler(h2);

for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Sample message");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

This code is adding above message instantly. What am I missing? My purpose is to not let too much disk I/O happen. Please help

Answer (score 2):

The third constructor argument in

```
Handler h2 = new MemoryHandler(h, 10, Level.ALL);
```

defines the *push level*, i.e. if a message of the given level or above it is logged, the MemoryHandler will push it to the configured downstream handler ([jdk documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/MemoryHandler.html)).

I don't think, that the MemoryHandler is suitable for the purpose you'd like to achieve. You could create your own implementation of a MemoryHandler with a fixed size buffer, that flushes whenever the buffer is full. But consider the drawbacks of this approach: log messages can get lost when the application terminates, flushing may involve blocking I/O and you cannot determine which thread will have to execute that I/O.

Alternatively you could think about using another proven logging framework, like logback or log4j2. These generally offer more advanced functionality. I suggest to look for asynchronous logging.

Answer (score 2):

You have to extend the MemoryHandler to provide custom push behavior.  You can do this by setting the push level to `ALL` overriding the push method or by setting the push level to `OFF` and then manually issuing a [push](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/MemoryHandler.html#push--) from the [publish](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/MemoryHandler.html#publish-java.util.logging.LogRecord-) method.

If you want to only start logging after a number of log records are seen then you want to create something like:

```
public class PopoffHandler extends MemoryHandler {

    private long count;
    private final long size;

    public PopoffHandler(Handler target, int size) {
        super(target, size, Level.ALL);
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void push() {
        if (count == size) {
            super.push();
        } else {
            ++count;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setPushLevel(Level newLevel) {
        if (newLevel == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        super.setPushLevel(Level.ALL);
    }
}
```

If you want to log records in groups then you want to do something like:

```
public class ChunkedHandler extends MemoryHandler {

    private long count;
    private final long size;

    public ChunkedHandler(Handler target, int size) {
        super(target, size, Level.OFF);
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void publish(LogRecord record) {
        super.publish(record);
        if (++count % size == 0L) {
            super.push();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setPushLevel(Level newLevel) {
        if (newLevel == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        super.setPushLevel(Level.OFF);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `push()` method calls `super.push()` twice. so the `count == size` branch serves no purpose.

Comment: @JustinM.Keyes Fixed. Thanks!